# How to call a method/an action inside UIViewController from custom UIView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller, action

In my iOS's project, in Swift, I have a custom `UIView` which include a `Button`.
This view is part of a UIViewController's view. 
When I touch the button from my custom view, I would like to fire a method inside my `UIViewController`.

What is the best practice to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use protocol/delegate:

```
protocol TapHandler {
func tapped()
}


class MyView: UIVieww {
weak var tapHandler: TapHandler?

/// button tap handler
@obj func yourTapFunctionInsideView() {
tapHandler?.tap()
}
}

class MyViewController: UIViewController, TapHandler {
var view: MyView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
view?.tapHandler = self
}

func tapped() {
/// tapped
}
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `view.tapHandler = self` _crash_ as you have not instantiated `view`? Just asking !

Comment: @ShubhamBakshi my dear friend. This code even will not be compiled. Obviously, this is a typo.

Comment: Yeah, ok , Thanks :P